# The road injuries are of major concern in Indian metro cities

Tags: prepositions

In the above sentence, Is it correct if I add **'of"** in front of **major concern.**
OR Is it okay, "a major concern'

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. To answer your question: yes, correct to add *of*. I wouldn't speak "The road injuries are major concern..." but will understand if it were the headline of a newspaper.

Comment: Either "of major concern" or "a major concern" works above.  It's largely a matter of style.  "... are major concern ...", however, is not a very good choice.